# undefined is always returned after mongoose delete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

running this gave me undefined at the console.log (like.user) and led to not updating Post and User schéma at (2 and 3 ==> ).

The problem is the 1==> the like variable is returning undefined

if you think there is an enhancement in this code suggestions will be welcomed

```
    exports.deleteLike = async (req, res) => {
              const userId = req.params.userId;
              const postId = req.params.postId;
              await Like.find({ post: postId, user: userId }).then((p) => {
              if (p.length !== 0) {
  1 ==>  const like = Like.deleteOne({ _id: p[0]._id }).then((del) => {  
                if (del.deletedCount === 1)  {
  2 ==> Post.updateOne({ _id: like.post },{ $pull:{ likes: like.id }, $inc:{ 
           LikesCount:-1}});
  3 ==> User.updateOne({ _id: like.user }, { $pull: { likes: like.id } });
                   // Delete like from users collection
                    console.log(" like.user", like.user)
                    }
                      });
                console.log(like.user);
                  return res.json({en: "Disliked"}).status("200");
                } else  res.json({en: "Already Disliked"}).status(200);
              }); };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it : working with the array P

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate(
          { _id: p[0].user },
          { $pull: { likes: p[0]._id } }
        ) .then((user) => {
          console.log("User updated    ");
        })
```